# db.transaction inside an for loop

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I need to do an db.transaction with the result of an for loop. But before the db.transaction completes the next iteration happens for the loop.

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {

tx.executeSql("select * from unassigned_item", [], function(tx, res) {
    var list = '';

    if (res != null && res.rows != null && res.rows.length>0) { 

        for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = res.rows.item(i);
            var serial = row.serialno;
            var id = row.unassigned_itemid;
            var theSerialNo = row.serialno;

            tx.executeSql("select * from unassigned_item where serialno="+ serial + "", [], function(tx, res) {
                });

            if(row.serialno.indexOf("'")>-1){
                theSerialNo = theSerialNo.replace(/'/g,"\\'");
            }
            list = list + '<li data-icon="false"><a onClick="selectedSerialNo(\'' + theSerialNo + '\', +\'' +  id + '\');">' + theSerialNo + '</a></li>';
            //list = list + '<li data-icon="false"><a onClick="selectedSerialNo(\'' + theSerialNo + '\', +\'' +  id + '\');">' + serial + '</a></li>'
        }
    }
    //list = list + '<li data-icon="false"><a onClick="selectedSerialNo(\'NEW\', 0);">ADD_NEW</a></li>'
    $("#serial_suggestions li").remove();
    $("#serial_suggestions").append(list);

});
},function(){

},function(){


});
```

How can i acheive this ??

Comment: It's worth to say that in most cases SQL requests inside loop is bad thing. Are you sure you can't merge these requests into one? Moreover, maybe you can merge them with first request? Using `JOIN`, for example?

Comment: No i need to customize my send SQL query based on the result of the first one ..I have updated my code . pls c it

Comment: You select whole table and then select again whole table, but in multiple requests, splitting table into rows' groups by `serialno`. Doesn't sound as good plan, does it? What do you really want to achieve with this?

Comment: I have an table with an coloumn serialno , In that coloumn if there is an duplicate rows i have to append an text to both the serial no and if not i want to append another set of text. So i need two sql queries to be executed.

Comment: So: 1. There is table with column `serialno`. 2. If there are duplicate **values** in this column, what text to what place do you want to append? And if value is unique one, what text to what place do you want to append?

Comment: If the second tx.executeSql has more than 1 row i will append serialno with "dup" and if not i will append it with "org"

Comment: What about request `SELECT COUNT(*) as 'count', serialno FROM unassigned_item GROUP BY serialno` and checking `row.serialno` and `row.count`? It works fast, it is easy, there is only 1 request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db operations are asynchronous, so you can't use it in a for loop if you expect the next iteration to be done after the previous one is finished.

What you can do is use a variable as a counter and check for its value in the success callback of executeSql.

Something like this (sorry no time to check deeper what your function is supposed to do):

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("select * from unassigned_item", [], function (tx, res) {
        var list = '';
        if (res != null && res.rows != null && res.rows.length > 0) {
            var i = 0;
            function iteration(i, rows) {
                var row = res.rows.item(i);
                var serial = row.serialno;
                var id = row.unassigned_itemid;
                var theSerialNo = row.serialno;
                tx.executeSql("select * from unassigned_item where serialno=" + serial + "", [], function (tx, res) {
                    if (row.serialno.indexOf("'") > -1) {
                        theSerialNo = theSerialNo.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
                    }
                    list = list + '<li data-icon="false"><a onClick="selectedSerialNo(\'' + theSerialNo + '\', +\'' + id + '\');">' + theSerialNo + '</a></li>';
                    i += 1;
                    if (i < rows.length)
                        iteration(i, rows);
                    else
                        theEnd();
                });
            }
            function theEnd() {
                $("#serial_suggestions li").remove();
                $("#serial_suggestions").append(list);
            }

            iteration(i, rows);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Even though it should work (`i += 1` instead of `i++` looks exotic, but whatever), I still insist not only that 1001 SQL requests (for 1000 elements) are ridiculous, but also that showing the way for doing these "1001" is like participation in a crime.

Comment: Yea This one worked . Thanks @Regent : Thanks for your tips !

Comment: @Regent, sorry for participating to the crime, I must confess I didn't even look at what the code was supposed do do. About the += thing, I could also have wrote if(++i ... but I find it clearer to read having the increment in it's own line, don't you? And I would find ugly a line with just i++ (personal tastes I guess...)